# Python read Excel cell data validation

Tags: python, excel, artificial-intelligence, data-science

How can I read Excel cell data validation rules in Python?

from `openpyxl.cell`, I can read only value, is_date, font, border, fill, umber_format, alignment, data_type. There is no data validation rule read in this API.

The reason I need to read data validation rules, because I am comparing Master template with the data submitted version of the Master template by client so that I can validate metadata including data validation rules in Excel so that we can identify that original template is not changed.

For example: the following is the way to write Data Validation in Python. How could I find API to read data validation from Excel Cell.

```
worksheet.data_validation('B25', {'validate': 'integer',
                                  'criteria': 'between',
                                  'minimum': 1,
                                  'maximum': 100,
                                  'input_title': 'Enter an integer:',
                                  'input_message': 'between 1 and 100'})
```

Will `xlwings` be of any help?

Thanks
Anant

Comment: Not sure of APIs to do so but you can read the validations from the xml file.  An xlsx file is a zip file with the validations in an XML file at ```\xl\worksheets\SHEETNAME.xml```

Comment: Have you found an API for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I read the API document and didn't find it, but through the source code reading, you can get it in the following ways

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('validation.xlsx')

ws = wb2.active

for one_val_obj in ws.data_validations.dataValidation:
    for k, v in one_val_obj.__dict__.items():
        print(k, v)
"""
sqref A1
showDropDown None
imeMode None
operator None
formula1 "数据验证1,数据验证2"
formula2 None
allowBlank True
showErrorMessage True
showInputMessage True
type list
promptTitle None
errorStyle None
error None
prompt None
errorTitle None

"""
```